# How to safely allow user to delete responses from Firebase-queue?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-queue

I'm using Firebase with Angular2 and Firebase-queue as a batch server.

Clients send tasks to the server and sometime they are waiting for a response.

Client can read the response using the request id. But then, what happens to the response ? I guess only the client can delete it but I don't really like to give `.write` to the client.

So I'm trying to figure out a way to secure this `.write` access.

**Question: Is It possible to give `.read` and `.write` access only to the user that own the request key?**

The response itself and even the `/responses` node would not be readable for the others.

I'm trying to avoid people(evil) deleting responses before the user can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Frank van Puffelen answered the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422657/return-task-results-using-firebase-queue/36427772#36427772).

If I only want auth user to able to use it, I should use the following rules right?

```
"responses": {
  ".read": "false",
  ".write": "false",
  "$responses": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```